# How do I call an overridden method one level up in java?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class.
  I have a class2 that extends base class.
  I have a class3 that extends class2.
  I have overridden abstract baseclass.method1 in both class2 and class3.
  in class3.method1, I call super.method1 and the error I get is that I can't
directly call the abstract method in baseclass.
  but I don't want to, I just want to go one level up, I want to call class2.method1, not baseclass.method1.
  How to do that?

Comment: Seems more like a "class2 extends BC" "class3 extends BC", and not "class3 extends class2" so what you get is exactly what you should.

Answer (score 1):

`.super()` in class3 should call methods defined in class2.

Answer (score 0):

I withdraw the question, it turns out class2 had a typo in it so the method1 didn't have the same name. whoops.

Comment: ahhh, never did that before. doesn't seem to be a good reason available. "programmer made typo" doesn't seem to be there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should work. Class3.method1() super calls Class2.method1, don't understand the problem *__*